# SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "temp_table_name" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to create a temporary table in my stored function in Postgresql. The language I am using is "plpgsql". 
When I run the stored function it throws an `SQL Error [42P01].`

**Exact Error**

> : "Query execution failed . 
>                  Reason:
>                  SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "temp_table" does .
>                  not exist"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_str_dsl_lp_ung(x int8)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql volatile
AS $function$
declare 

--variables
variab int :=0;
begin  

    CREATE temporary TABLE temp_table  (a int8, b int8) ;
    insert into temp_table (a,b) select (a,b) from existing_table;
end
$function$
```

I want to create a temp table to store some records temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

You have few issues with your code

1. You have defined the function as `stable`  which, as per
   [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) is not allowed and you would receive an error while executing.

   > ERROR:  CREATE TABLE is not allowed in a non-volatile function

To fix this, you must change it to `VOLATILE`

2. `insert into temp_table (a,b) select (a,b)` doesn't work because
   parenthesising the columns implies that you are treating them as
   `record` and not individual columns.

Fixing these two, your function should work fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_str_dsl_lp_ung(color smallint,
lpcount integer, update_userid character varying, OUT lp integer)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql volatile
AS $function$
declare 

--variables
variab int :=0;
begin  

    CREATE temporary TABLE temp_table  (a int8, b int8) ;
    insert into temp_table (a,b) select a,b from existing_table;
end
$function$
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5e47aece9b2fb3902798d5a3ae19472d)

Comment: @ffs : Did you check the demo? it's working fine. You are probably making a mistake while writing your code which we won't know.